# How to continue trying to attempt a connection if connection fails

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, pyinstaller

(python)

So I have a basic connection that works fine as long as whatever I want to connect to is online. The code is turned into a standalone using pyinstaller. If whatever I want to connect to is offline, when the standalone program is run it gives me a "Failed to excecute script test" (test being name of the program). How can I make it so it continues trying to establish a connection until it succeeds? Here is what I attempted below.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

while True:
        result = s.connect_ex((host,port))
        if result == 0:
                break
        else:
                sleep_for = random.randrange(1,10)
                time.sleep( sleep_for )
                pass

Func1()
Func2()
s.close()
```

Comment: `result == 0` means connection fail?

Comment: You can't reconnect a socket, even if the prior connect failed. You have to close it and create a new one.

Comment: result == 0 means its is a success according to the documentation for connect_ex. What I am attempting in my code is if 0 (no errors) then continue to other functions, else if 1 (some sort of error or connection failed), then sleep for sometime and re-enter the loop(try again)

Comment: I can read your code. You need to read my comment again. What you're doing isn't valid.

Comment: i understand your comment and will keep that in mind. I was responding to poojan.

Answer (score -1):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket-objects) for `connect_ex` says:

> Like `connect(address)`, return an error indicator instead of raising an exception for errors returned by the C-level connect() call (other problems, such as “host not found,” can still raise exceptions)

That means that you still need to catch exceptions in order to infinitely retry to connect. In order to not make double work: processing `connect_ex` return value and catching exceptions, you can switch from using `connect_ex` to `connect` method and rewrite your code like this:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

while True:
        try:
                s.connect((host,port))
                break
        except socket.error:
                sleep_for = random.randrange(1,10)
                time.sleep( sleep_for )
                pass

Func1()
Func2()
s.close()
```

Comment: This doesn't solve anything, it's just another way of writing the same code.

Comment: I will give it a try and see how it goes but for now I would have to agree with the above comment. Thanks for the input.